An agent built in Copilot Studio does not provide complete answers to questions
I have built an agent in Microsoft Copilot Studio that answers questions based on a document I uploaded. While the answers it provides are not incorrect, they are incomplete. However, when I upload the same document to Microsoft Copilot in the regular 365 environment, the answers are complete. Is there a way to control or influence the generated answers in Copilot Studio?
The only thing I could think of was improving the instruction, which seems to act as a system prompt. However, this did not resolve the issue. When I created a completely new agent in Classic Mode, the answers were correct and complete. Unfortunately, in Classic Mode, I lose some of the generative AI functionality I need for autonomously processing emails.

Could you please refer the document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-copilot-agents-integrated-apps?view=o365-worldwide

This document doesn't provide me with the answer to the indicated problem, does it?

Here's an example of how you might refine the prompt and instructions:
**Prompt:**
Please read the following document and answer questions based on its content.

**Instructions:**
1. Focus on providing detailed and complete answers.
2. Highlight key points and relevant information from the document.
3. If multiple sections of the document are relevant to a question, combine information from those sections to provide a comprehensive answer.

**Document:**
[Insert well-structured document content here with headings and bullet points]

By refining the prompt and instructions, improving document structure, and iterating through testing, you should be able to enhance the quality and completeness of the answers generated by your agent in Copilot Studio.
Reference Documents:-
1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-copilot/extensibility/copilot-studio-agent-builder#governance
2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-copilot/extensibility/copilot-studio-agent-builder-publish#create-the-agent
3.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365-copilot/extensibility/copilot-studio-agent-builder#data-processing
